# Sending a flexible Amount of Data over Network by using Asio (Boost)

Tags: c++, serialization, boost-asio

I got a client and a server application which will send each other data by using the Asio (Standalone) library. Both applications consists of two (logical) parts:

1. A high level part: dealing with complex objects e.g. users, permissions,...
2. A low level part: sending data over network between client and server

Let's assume the complex objects are already serialized by using [Protocoll Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) and the low level part of the application receives the data as std::string from the high level part. I would like to use this function from [Protocoll Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial) for this job:

> bool **SerializeToString**(string* output) const;: serializes the message
>   and stores the bytes in the given string. Note that the bytes are
>   binary, not text; we only use the string class as a convenient
>   container.

And say I transfer this data with async_write on the client side:

```
size_t dataLength = strlen(data);

//writes a certain number of bytes of data to a stream.
asio::async_write(mSocket,
                      asio::buffer(data, dataLength),
                      std::bind(&Client::writeCallback, this,
                                std::placeholders::_1,   
                                std::placeholders::_2));
```

How can I read this data on the server side? I don't know how much data I will have to read. Therefore this will not work (length is unknown):

```
 asio::async_read(mSocket,
                     asio::buffer(mResponse, length),
                     std::bind(&Server::readCallback, this,
                               std::placeholders::_1,
                               std::placeholders::_2));
```

What is the best way to solve this problem? I could think of two solutions:

1. Append a 'special' character at the end of `data` and read until I reach this 'end of data signal'. The problem is, what if this character appears in `data` somehow? I don't know how Protocoll Buffers serializes my data.
2. Send a binary string with `size_of_data + data` instead of `data`. But I don't know how to serialize the size in an platform independent way, add it to the binary data and extract it again.

Edit: Maybe I could use this:

```
    uint64_t length = strlen(data);
    uint64_t nwlength = htonl(length);
    uint8_t len[8];
    len[0] = nwlength >> 56;
    len[1] = nwlength >> 48;
    len[2] = nwlength >> 40;
    len[3] = nwlength >> 32;
    len[4] = nwlength >> 24;
    len[5] = nwlength >> 16;
    len[6] = nwlength >> 8;
    len[7] = nwlength >> 0;

    std::string test(len);

    mRequest = data;
    mRequest.insert(0, test);
```

and send mRequest to the server? **Any traps or caveats with this code?
How could I read the length on server side and the content afterwards?**
Maybe like this:

```
void Server::readHeader(){

    asio::async_read(mSocket,
                     asio::buffer(header, HEADER_LENGTH),
                     std::bind(&Server::readHeaderCallback, this,
                               std::placeholders::_1,
                               std::placeholders::_2),
                     asio::transfer_exactly(HEADER_LENGTH));
}

void Server::readHeaderCallback(const asio::error_code& error,
                                        size_t bytes_transferred){

    if(!error && decodeHeader(header, mResponseLength)){
        //reading header finished, now read the content
        readContent();
    }
    else{
        if(error) std::cout << "Read failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
        else std::cout << "decodeHeader failed \n";       
    }
}

void Server::readContent(){

    asio::async_read(mSocket,
                     asio::buffer(mResponse, mResponseLength),
                     std::bind(&Server::readContentCallback, this,
                               std::placeholders::_1,
                               std::placeholders::_2),
                     asio::transfer_exactly(mResponseLength));
}

void Server::readContentCallback(const asio::error_code& error,
                                         size_t bytes_transferred){
    if (!error){
       //handle content
    }
    else{
        //@todo remove this cout
        std::cout << "Read failed: " << error.message() << "\n";      
    }
}
```

Please note that I try to use `transfer_exactly`. Will this work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24428498/85371

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When sending variable length messages over a stream-based protocol, there are generally three solutions to indicate message boundaries:

- Use a delimiter to specify message boundaries.  The [`async_read_until()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until.html) operations provide a convenient way to read variable length delimited messages.  When using a delimiter, one needs to consider the potential of a *delimiter collision*, where the delimiter appears within the contents of a message, but does not indicate a boundary.  There are various techniques to handle delimiter collisions, such as escape characters or escape sequences.
- Use a fixed-length header with a variable-length body protocol.  The header will provide meta-information about the message, such as the length of the body.  The official Asio [chat example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.chat) demonstrates one way to handle fixed-length header and variable-length body protocols.

  If binary data is being sent, then one will need to consider handling [byte-ordering](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Endianness).  The [`hton()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) and `ntoh()` family of functions can help with byte-ordering.  For example, consider a protocol that defines the field as two bytes in network-byte-order (big-endian) and a client reads the field as a `uint16_t`.  If the value `10` is sent, and a little-endian machine reads it without converting from network-order to local-order, then the client will read the value as `2560`.  The Asio chat example avoids handling endianness by encoding the body length to string instead of a binary form.
- Use the connection's end-of-file to indicate the end of a message.  While this makes sending and receiving messages easy, it limits the sender to only one message per connection.  To send an additional message, one would need to established another connection.

---

A few observations about the code:

- The Protocol Buffers' `SerializeToString()` function serializes a message to a *binary* form.  One should avoid using *text* based functions, such as [`strlen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen), on the serialized string.  For instance, `strlen()` may incorrectly determine the length, as it will treat the first byte with a value of `0` as the terminating null byte, even if that byte is part of the encoded value.
- When providing an explicitly sized buffer to an operation via `asio::buffer(buffer, n)`, the default completion condition of [`transfer_all`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/transfer_all.html) will function the same as [`transfer_exactly(n)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/transfer_exactly.html).  As such, the duplicate use of variables can be removed:

  ```cpp
  asio::async_read(mSocket,
                   asio::buffer(header, HEADER_LENGTH),
                   std::bind(&Server::readHeaderCallback, this,
                            std::placeholders::_1,
                            std::placeholders::_2));
  ```
- The `htonl()` overloads support `uint16_t` and `uint_32t`, not `uint64_t`.
- Asio supports [scatter/gather operations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/buffers.html), allowing a receive operation to scatter-read into multiple buffers, and transmit operations can gather-write from multiple buffers.  As such, one does not necessarily need to have both the fixed-length header and message-body contained with a single buffer.

  ```cpp
  std::string body_buffer;
  body.SerializeToString(&body_buffer);
  std::string header_buffer = encode_header(body_buffer.size());

  // Use "gather-write" to send both the header and data in a
  // single write operation.
  std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> buffers;
  buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(header_buffer));
  buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(body_buffer));
  boost::asio::write(socket_, buffers);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

client must call

```
socket.shutdown(asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
socket.close();
```

on the server size read until EOF detected

```
std::string reveive_complete_message(tcp::socket& sock)
{
  std::string json_msg;
  asio::error_code error;
  char buf[255];

  while (1)
  {
    //read some data up to buffer size 
    size_t len = sock.read_some(asio::buffer(buf), error);

    //store the received buffer and increment the total return message 
    std::string str(buf, len);
    json_msg += str;
    if (error == asio::error::eof)
    {
      //EOF received, the connection was closed by client
      break;
    }
    else if (error)
    {
      throw asio::system_error(error);
    }
  }

  return json_msg;
}
```